# Angular Add/Remove class on mouseOvered from the .ts file

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

I am using Angular 4 and I have this div on my html template:

```
<div [class.myCssClass]="mouseOvered" (mouseout)="mouseOvered=false" (mouseover)="mouseOvered=true">Hover me</div>
```

This works great but I would like to do this same thing from the .ts component file instead.

How can I do this from the .ts component file?

Comment: What do you mean by "from the .ts component"?

Comment: yes, from app.component.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to me, The best way would be to use a HostListener.

For a component to listen on itself on the mouse events you can use:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component'
  template: '<div [class.myCssClass]="mouseover"'
})
class MyComponent {


   mouseover:boolean;

    @HostListener('mouseover')
    onMouseOver() {
        this.mouseover = true;
    }

    @HostListener('mouseout')
    onMouseOut() {
        this.mouseover = false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `[ngClass]`.

```
<div [ngClass]="{  overedClass:  mouseOvered === true }" 
        (mouseout)="onMouseOut()"
        (mouseover)="onMouseOver()">Hover me</div>
```

... and in your .ts:

```
// contains name of any class that you want to apply
private overedClass: string = 'myCssClass';
private mouseOvered: boolean;

onMouseOver() {
    this.mouseOvered  = true;
} 

onMouseOut() {
    this.mouseOvered  = false;
}
```